# Mysql won't show my databases

Tags: mysql, database

After I restart my computer, my databases doesn't show when I run the command `show databases;`
It only shows the following:
information_schema 
test

If i go to `/usr/local/var/mysql`, my databases files are there.

I'm on OS X 10.6.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an `/etc/my.cnf` file? if so, `cat` (display) it to see where it thinks your database files should be (the `datadir=` line).

If you don't have a `my.cnf` file, create one as follows:

```
[client]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port = 3306
basedir = /usr/local/mysql/
datadir = /where/your/data/files/are/
```

From what you are saying, your datadir should be `/usr/local/var/mysql/`.

Restart `mysql` and see whether the databases turn up.

Answer (score 1):

You may logged into the wrong user. Are you logged in as root? Usually the root user will have access to all the databases. Then you can give privileges to other users.

Comment: I'm logged in as root